# #1005 - ( error code: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") how to fix?

Tags: mysql

It says there is an error but I can't figure out why.

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Adresa`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Adresa` (
  `Adresa_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `PSC` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Ulice` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Mesto` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Adresa_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Clenstvi`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Clenstvi` (
  `Clenstvi_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Klub` ENUM("Standard", "Premium") NULL,
  `DatumExpirace` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Clenstvi_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;




-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Kontakt_zakaznik`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Kontakt_zakaznik` (
  `Kontakt_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Adresa_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Telefon` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Kontakt_ID`, `Adresa_ID`),
  INDEX `Adresa_ID_idx` (`Adresa_ID` ASC) ,     
  CONSTRAINT `Adresa_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Adresa_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Adresa` (`Adresa_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Kontakt_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Kontakt_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Zakaznik_informace` (`Kontakt_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;





-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Zakaznik_informace`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Zakaznik_informace` (
  `Zakaznik_informace_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Kontakt_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Jmeno` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Prijmeni` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Datum_narozeni` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Pohlavi` ENUM("Můž", "Žena") NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Zakaznik_informace_ID`, `Kontakt_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Zakaznik_informace_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Zakaznik_informace_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Zakaznik` (`ID`)  
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Zakaznik`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Zakaznik` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Clenstvi_ID` INT NULL,
  `Zakaznik_informace_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `Zakaznik_informace_ID`, `Clenstvi_ID`),
  INDEX `Clenstvi_ID_idx` (`Clenstvi_ID` ASC) ,  
  CONSTRAINT `Clenstvi_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Clenstvi_ID` )   
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Clenstvi` (`Clenstvi_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

t
This is all I have but it just wont work because of the following error:

> #1005 - Can't create table `mydb`.`kontakt_zakaznik` (error code:: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server but your syntax is *clearly* MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely to be the reference to table `Zakaznik_informace`, which you have not yet created at the time you get the error.

You must create all referenced tables before you can make another table reference them with a foreign key.

So in this case, just edit your create script to move `Zakaznik_informace` before `Kontakt_zakaznik`. You must also move `Zakaznik` before `Zakaznik_informace`.